# Mapping Ecclesiastical Parish Data?

Tags: import, table, visualisation, reverse-geocoding

I am looking for a way to plot data relating to the number of people in a given location - the location being an ecclesiastical parish. So I need software that will allow me to import a map of parishes in a diocese.  As an ancient Geography graduate (1961 degree) I have no experience of digital mapping.

Do I need to research a grid reference for each parish to add to the people data I already have?

Comment: what software are you planning to use?  where is your data coming from? where is your study area?

Comment: OpenStreetMap has Parishes Example Ailsworth CP (Peterborough) http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1608496 - if you have an area of interest please update your question - source http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Peterborough#Parishes_in_Peterborough

Answer (score 1):

The [Vision of Britain](http://www.visionofbritain.org.uk/) has [Ecclesiastical Parish boundaries](http://www.visionofbritain.org.uk/types/type_page.jsp?unit_type=ECC_PAR) but I can't see them listed on the data download page. It may be worth contacting the project to see if they can supply them. Or you could consider using Civil Parishes as @Mapperz suggests.

In both cases I think the issue will be that Britain is not completely covered in parishes.